# Where are auto generated SSH keys stored in Windows using azure cli --generate-ssh-keys

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to create linux VM with azure cli from local machine. I was able to create VM using following command but now when I want to ssh into the VM, I need to have public key on my local machine?

How can I get the required public key to connect to vm using `ssh azureuser@publicIpAddress`? Where are the ssh keys generated by `--generate-ssh-keys` and how to get it?

```
az vm create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM \
  --image UbuntuLTS \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```

I used PowerShell 7.0 with elevated privileges to run the above command

**Solved**

Update 1:

- SSH keys are generated in c:\users\.ssh\ when you use `--generate-ssh-keys` switch
- If there are already file with name `id_rsa` & `id_rsa.pub` then it might be conflicting and you can use another switch `--ssh-key-values /path/to/public/key` to specify different file name
- After that if you get `Permissions for 'private-key' are too open` error then follow steps mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open)

Comment: The keys are stored in the `~/.ssh` directory. [Generate keys automatically during deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed#generate-keys-automatically-during-deployment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create) for `--generate-ssh-keys`:

> Generate SSH public and private key files if missing. The keys will be stored in the ~/.ssh directory.

Which will by default create a private `id_rsa` and public `id_rsa.pub` SSH key pair in the `~/.ssh` directory if they don't exist. If you already have existing SSH keys in that location, it will just use those and *not* overwrite them.

On Windows this is the `C:\Users\username\.ssh` directory.

Additionally, you could also pass in a specific SSH public key path with `--ssh-key-values`:

```
az vm create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM \
  --image UbuntuLTS \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --ssh-key-values /path/to/public/key
```

This is particularly useful if you have created SSH keys in another location with `ssh-keygen`.

As [@Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228754/how-can-i-get-auto-generated-ssh-keys-in-azure/62230519#comment110057275_62228754) pointed out in the comments, you could have a look at [Generate keys automatically during deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed#generate-keys-automatically-during-deployment) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it under

> **C:\Users\<<*your-user-name*>>\.ssh**

When you create a VM for the first time you get the below message as well

> SSH key files 'C:\Users\<<*your-user-name*>>\.ssh\id_rsa' and
>   'C:\Users\<<*your-user-name*>>\.ssh\id_rsa.pub' have been generated under ~/.ssh
>   to allow SSH access to the VM. If using machines without permanent
>   storage, back up your keys to a safe location.

For subsequent VM creations, the same key pair is used and you don't see the message again.

(*I verfied using Windows OS, creating a linux VM with RedHat:RHEL:7-RAW:7.4.2018010506 image via Azure CLI*)